# Is there a convenient way to check if at least a certain number of conditions are true?

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Is there an easy way to check if a minimum number of conditions have been met? Like, let's say that I've asked somebody to pick at least 4 days of the week. Is there some sort of way that I can check that they've picked at least 4 days? It'd be a real pain to write out all the ands and ors for the possible conditions. Maybe this could be done in java with like a `switch` statement, but in general is there a straightforward way?

I was thinking it'd be easiest to add up the value of all the boolean statements, and then see if they sum to at least 4. Some pseudo code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
if ((input.contains("mon") + input.contains("tues") + ... + input.contains("sun")) >=4){
    //do stuff
}
```

But I'm not sure if that's really a valid way to do it? Help?

Comment: What language/technology are you using?

Comment: @slugster typically use Java, but this was in reference to a php problem I've had

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a simple method to count the total number of days selected:

```
private boolean moreThanFourSelected(input) {
    String days[] = { "mon", "tues", ..., "sun" };
    int total = 0;
    for (String day : days) {
        if (input.contains(day)) total++;
    }
    return total >= 4;
}
```

Comment: So there isn't really a way to do it with boolean operators? I like your way, I'm just curious.

Comment: @jhobbie I'm sure there could be some way to do it with boolean operators, I just thought this was easier.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, I'm assuming that `input` is of type `String`, and since you don't specify a language, I'll just use C# in this example, since it's pretty cool and stuff.

So if this string is supposed to look something like this:

> Monday Tuesday Wednesday Orange

and that's what it actually contains, the following code:

```
if(MinimumNumberOfDaysSelected(input))
{
   // Condition is met (atleast 4 selected).
}
else
{
   // Condition not met (less than 4 selected).
}

public bool MinimumNumberOfDaysSelected(string input)
{
   string[] days = input.Split(' ');
   int count;

   foreach(string day in days)
   {
      switch(day)
      {
         case "Monday":
            count++;
         break;
         case "Tuesday":
            count++;
         break;
         case "Wednesday":
            count++;
         break;
         case "Thursday":
            count++;
         break;
         case "Friday":
            count++;
         break;
         case "Saturday":
            count++;
         break;
         case "Sunday":
            count++;
         break;
         default:
         break;
      }
   }

   return count >= 4 ? true : false;
}
```

would return whether there are atleast 4 days selected - or not. It also assumes you're using a `space` to separate the words. I think it would be easier if we knew what language you were using and what kind of format your input is in.

Answer (score 0):

In general(Not only for days), use a HashMap to store the condition as key and selection as value as below,

```
        HashMap<String, Boolean> selectionMap=new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

In this way, the selected and not selected count can be easily calculated based on the entries in the hashmap. Whenever there is selection or not, make an entry in this hashmap and count the entries finally. This can also be used for selection alone. This way will be very helpful if we don't know the total number of conditions initially.

Here is the code,

```
    HashMap<String, Boolean> selectionMap=new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    selectionMap.put("Mon", true);
    selectionMap.put("Tue", true);
    selectionMap.put("Wed", false);
    selectionMap.put("Thur", false);

    int selectedCount=0;
    int notSelectedCount=0;
    boolean s=false;
    for(String key : selectionMap.keySet())
    {
         s=selectionMap.get(key);
         if(s)
             selectedCount++;
         else
             notSelectedCount++;

    }

    System.out.println("Selected Count : "+selectedCount);
    System.out.println("Not Selected Count : "+notSelectedCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is to go with Enum rather than String. For example from my perspective, you can first define enum.

```
enum Day {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday;

    public static Day forName(String name) {
        for (Day value : values()) {
            if (value.name().equals(name)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then do whatever you need with EnumSet. So if you want number of days included;

```
public int numOfDays(String[] strings){
    EnumSet<Day> days = EnumSet.noneOf(Day.class);
    for (String string : strings) {
        Day day = Day.valueOf(string);
        if(day != null)
            days.add(day);
    }
    return days.size(); // return days if you need what days are included
}
```